# Rails 4: Active Record get entries based on belongs_to relation's properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've not been able to figure this one out -- perhaps I've missed something in the docs. I want to get all of the articles that are associated with published issues. (That is, `article.issue.is_published = true`.)

I have two models:

```
# Article model
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  ...
end

# Issue model
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  ...
end
```

From what I understand, I can run something like this:

```
Article.includes(:issues)
  .where('issue.is_published = true')
  .references(:issues)
```

But I get nothing but funky business on the other end. All of the examples I've found have one-to-many relationships going the other way - I assumed that I've gotten something wrong with the naming convention, but no combination of "issue" and "issues" seems to work any better.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Relevant docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes

Comment: And: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do a `joins` instead of `includes` here. This translates to a SQL inner join. `Article.joins(:issue).where(issues: {is_published: true})`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Out of curiosity, why does the `includes` not do this? Looking at the documentation, i thought that's what was happening...?

Comment: `includes` functions more like a left outer join. The conditions you pass into the `where` are conditions on the included model, not on the Article (thus the results will include Articles that don't have an issue_id). `includes` is generally used for eager loading associations to avoid N+1s.